# Move label with slider thumb

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sdk

Is there a way to move label (which show the value of slider) with the move of the slider thumb?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes see [this sample](https://github.com/elc/ELCSlider) .. 
Here, it's a UIPopoverController with CGRect. You can use that CGRect to give your UILabel frame whenever slider value changes.

Hope this helps...

Comment: then you should accept the answer which helped you Nimmi. Just like returning the favor? :)

Answer (score -1):

Use this library. It allow to put custom view over thumb.

https://github.com/Hitesh136/HASlider